# Batch file output without path/directory in front of the commands

Tags: batch-file, directory, path, output

So, as the title says i would like to remove the directory or path that gets put in front of called commands if i output a batch file into a text file.

For example i've got a batch file like that

```
call :sub>log.txt
    
:sub
SET ip=127.0.0.1
ping %ip%
```

What i get as output is this:

```
C:\Users\...>SET ip=127.0.0.1     
C:\Users...>ping 127.0.0.1 
pingoutput
```

What i want is this:

```
SET ip=127.0.0.1
ping 127.0.0.1
pingoutput
```

The path in front can get pretty annoying for deep directories.
The examples above are just this, examples. I want to create a batch file to install a sql database and different triggers and functions with the batch file, so i can easily deploy it on different pcs.

Edit says: @echo off at the beginning just completely removes a line, even the command itself.

Comment: The prefix is the prompt string of the console window, which can be changed with the [`prompt` command](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html). You could use `prompt $H`, for example, to get an empty prompt (actually `$H` represents a backspace character, but it has no effect here, though it will be contained in a file when you redirect into such), but I recommend not to use an empty prompt, because the console appears quite confusing then…

Comment: In my now distant knowledge, of using `$H`, @aschipfl, I remember it producing strange characters in the output file. Whether that has changed across different versions of Windows/cmd.exe/notepad.exe, I couldn't confirm, hence the reason I used just `$G` in my answer. Perhaps `$_` will provide a similar thing, except it will obviously include an additional empty line.

Comment: You're right, @Compo, I just played around and found out (on my Windows 7 machine), that `prompt $H` produces the sequence _BS_ + _SPACE_ + _BS_ (I guess this might be intended to truly clear the previous character on the console when _BS_ just moves back). So the only remaining possibilities to get an empty prompt text are `$M` on a local disk and `$+` with an empty `pushd`/`popd` buffer (both with command extensions enabled), both of which are not quite useful regarding said restrictions/dependencies…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If deep paths is your real issue, there's a simpler fix, you probably haven't thought of. Change the `prompt` string.

```bsh
@Prompt $G
Call :Sub 1> "log.txt"
@Prompt
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "IP=127.0.0.1"
%__APPDIR__%ping.exe %IP%
```

In the case above, I have changed the prompt string to just a greater than character, after calling the label, using `Prompt` without an argument returns it to its default again. Also as you can see, the `@` character prefix turns off echoing for those commands, so they aren't shown in your console or output file.

In the example above I used `$G` because it still differentiates commands from output, but you could obviously play around with it to find something you prefer.

To find out more about the options available, open a Command Prompt window, type `prompt /?`, press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, and read the information presented.

Comment: You should also notice in my code above, that I've included a `GoTo :EOF` instruction, which prevents the command parser from stepping back into the label again. _(You could optionally change that to a different actual label, or even replace it with `Exit /B`)_

Answer (score 2):

`@echo off` disables command `echo`ing. That is kind off the point. if you want to see the command, then `echo` each command while `@echo off` is enabled:

```
@echo off
call :sub>log.txt
goto :eof
:sub
echo set ip=127.0.0.1 & SET ip=127.0.0.1
echo ping %ip% & ping %ip%
```

or if you do not want to use the `& operator, just newlines will work:

```
@echo off
call :sub>log.txt
goto :eof  
:sub
echo set ip=127.0.0.1
SET ip=127.0.0.1
echo ping %ip%
ping %ip%
```

and completely without the `call`ing of the label:

```
@echo off
(echo set ip=127.0.0.1 & set ip=127.0.0.1
echo ping %ip% & ping %ip%)>log.txt
```